# Java to exe with referenced selenium libraries

Tags: java, selenium, exe, jsmooth

Ive done some research on this but can not seem to figure out how to make a program work if it has referenced libraries. I have a java program with dependencies on the selenium 2.12 libraries and I require making the program into an exe because I will have to run this program across several computers that do not have java installed. I have looked into JSmooth which everyone seems to recommend. Has anyone had experience with this that can help me out in setting this up?

Comment: *"I will have to run this program across several computers that do not have java installed."*  What, but you don't have to run it on various machines where Windows is not installed?  Use .NET.

Comment: [What about this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332548/running-a-java-program-as-an-exe-in-windows-without-jre-installed) I especially like the Andreas_D's answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK JSmooth does not allow you to run java on computer that does not have java installed, simply it downloads Java if it does not find it already installed.

You should tell JSmooth the external dependencies (jars) you need, placing them on the classpath as explained here http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html#N10166 .

If you then plan to create and installer for your app, you'll need to include also those jars inside it.

Comment: So would I not be able to run this program on computers without java installed? That was the main reason I required making it an exe, otherwise, Eclipse has a nice executable jar export function that I would have otherwise used.

Comment: You will be able to start it on computer not having Java installed. The first time the user executes it, tt will start, tell the user that it needs to download Java, download and install Java, then run your application. The second time, Java will already be there and your app will simply start. IIRC the eclipse executable jar export is even less than that, it does not create a .exe, simply a .jar file with a manifest, but you may be talking about another Eclipse plugin.