# auto run the java application from pen drive without java installed

Tags: java, batch-file

I developed a java application and converted it in to an exe file. When I plug in the thumb drive or pen drive, the application can launch in systems with java installed, but when I run it on a system where java non installed, it asks to install.
My question: Is there any technique or third party tool for launching the java application without installing the java on a system?

Its like plug the pendrive and launch java application.

Comment: First hit [here](http://bit.ly/SMZW0q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Quick search on SO gave this solution for packaging a Java App into an EXE and not needing to install the JRE.

[running a java program as an exe in windows without JRE installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332548/running-a-java-program-as-an-exe-in-windows-without-jre-installed)

Comment: Other solution just bundle the JRE and set jdk home path