# Wrap a executabe jar into .exe for using without jre installed

Tags: java, jar, exe, launch4j

I would like to wrap an executable jar into a .exe file in order to give it to associate. I used Launch4j and it works. However the others are not able to use it.  Error occurs always with Java version.

[image]

I found this question:

[Running a java program as an exe in Windows without JRE installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332548/running-a-java-program-as-an-exe-in-windows-without-jre-installed)

Is there nothing else more easy to use?

EDIT :

I slected prefer JRE rather than preferJDK und JRE window, that was the problem there.

Comment: did you tried https://www.excelsiorjet.com/?

Comment: To run Java you need JRE installed, it's simple as that.

Comment: No I didn't, at least not to the end. I found this difficult.

Comment: *"No I didn't"* 1) Tip: Add @Spara (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) *"Is there nothing else more easy to use? .. I found this difficult."* Reliable / robust deployment of a desktop app. is a lot trickier than people often guess.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you for that. Ok I didn't think so. Well if there is really not another way to do I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

In Launch4j, under JRE > Bundled JRE path, type something like `./runtime`. When you wrap your JAR file into an EXE, the EXE will look for a java runtime in the current directory under a subdirectory called "runtime". If you copy a Java runtime directory into the same directory as your wrapped EXE file, it will use it.

[image]

In Windows Explorer:

[image]

The "runtime" directory is the complete JRE directory, E.G. "jre1.8.0_201", but renamed. Inside there should be a bin folder and a lib folder and some other files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Magnus Bull. It sounds like a great idea but I solved my problem in an other way. In fact I slected prefer JRE rather than preferJDK under JRE window. Sorry, I didn't update my question !