# Run java application without installing the java on target machine

Tags: java, windows-installer, javaexe

I have created a Java application and made an installer for various platform. It works fine with me, but when it comes to the other machine, it requires Java to be installed on the target machine to run the Java application. For the Windows installer I created the .exe file with the help of Inno Setup and Launch4j, and included the JRE into the installer.

I want to run my Java application on the other Windows machine without installing Java. I need help to solve my problem.

Comment: I just wrote an answer. I'll mark this question as duplicate. You can read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172804/6099347).

Comment: @AniketSahrawat , the link given into the accepted answer does not open. I think you were in hurry to mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I asked you to visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172804/6099347 link.

Comment: you don't need to install java if u have bundled jre with it

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer , I was also expecting the same thing. But unfortunately, it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for native vm. Solution like GraalVM may help here. With GraalVM you can bundle your distribution as an executable.

https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/windows/

For Java native image take a look at,

https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/#native-images

Answer (score -2):

you can do it using Launch4j http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/
Launch4j wraps jars in Windows native executables and allows to run them like a regular Windows program

Comment: you forgot to mention that that you have to  bundle the jre or jdk with it.